# database connectivity using nhibernate for an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle10g, nhibernate-mapping

how to connect database(oracle) using nhibernate for an asp.net mvc application?
can anyone help..

Comment: Are you looking on how to set up NHibernate? There is nothing different that you'd need to set it up. You may want to decide on the strategy on how to inject NHibernate Session to each HttpRequest and also transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

http://nhbwithoracle.blogspot.com/

Nothing special has to be done for asp.net mvc integration.